# Relationship between class number and Legendre symbol

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose we have a prime $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ and $p>3$ with the property that for all primes $q<p/4$, we have that $\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)=-1$. I believe that in this case it is true that the class number of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-p}]$ is 1, but I am not sure how to prove this. Any ideas?

Comment: I presume you mean all non-square $q < p/4$?  Otherwise, the hypotheses are never met since $q=1$ is always a residue.

Comment: Actually, its worse than that.  Since, for instance, if $2$ and $3$ are both nonresidues, then $6$ will be a residue.  I guess you're assuming $q$ is prime?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot to state $q$ was prime.

Comment: The class number of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-p}]$ is one only for a finite number of primes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one , imaginary quadratic fields.

Comment: Moreover, your hypothesis is very unlikey to hold, since by Burgess bound and Vinogradov's amplification trick it is known that the size of the least quadratic non-residue $\pmod{p}$ is $\ll p^{\frac{1}{4\sqrt{e}}}$.

Comment: And anyway, by elementary means one has that the least quadratic non-residue is at most $1+\sqrt{p}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Minkowski's bound shows that every ideal class contains an element of norm at most
$$\sqrt{|-p|} \left( \frac{4}{\pi} \right) \frac{2!}{2^2} = \frac{2\sqrt{p}}{\pi}.$$
Using your hypotheses, can you find a way to show that all ideals of small norm are principal?

Comment: I made that observation already, and I was able to show that all prime ideals of such small norm are non-split, but I was not able to show that this implies they were principal.

Comment: @ruadan What does an inert prime look like?